# How do I open a specific port (30033) for Teamspeak?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I have a teamspeak server set up on Ubuntu 16.04, and I need to open port 30033 to transfer and upload files.

I can't find a direct answer on how to do this. How can I open port 30033?

Comment: Open it where? Is it closed? By what?

Comment: @Alpine Are you behind a [NAT router](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)? (Routers used [in homes and small offices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_(computing)#Access) are usually NAT routers.) [Do you actually need](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17207/22949) to [*forward* the port through your router](https://superuser.com/q/284051/105707), rather than to do anything in Ubuntu? Can you **[edit]** this to clarify that? Also, do you get errors when you run Teamspeak? Are you unable to connect on your own LAN? Why do you think you may need to do anything special?

Answer (score 1):

Usually *opening* a port refers to unblocking the port in the firewall. Ubuntu blocks nothing by default.

Applications (like Teamspeak) *bind* to ports that they use. Some mistake that activity for the application opening the port.

If you have not changed your firewall, and and if no application is already using port 30033, then your mission is already accomplished.